# Outbound network connections broken for HTTPd on CentOS after update

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, centos7, update

About 4 CentOS servers have been showing problems since a recent update. All of them can't connect to the outside world, specifically from the web server. Doing a `curl` or `ping` from the CLI works fine. Rebooting the server makes everything work again.

Any idea what could be wrong here? For the servers that will come, I would want to prevent a restart, of course... I suspect the network firmware updates (below) have messed something up.

SELinux should be disabled:

```
[root@server public_html]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

It's these updates that have been installed:

```
[root@server public_html]# cat /var/log/yum.log | grep "May 10"
May 10 07:38:54 Updated: filesystem.x86_64 3.2-25.el7
May 10 07:38:59 Updated: libgcc.x86_64 4.8.5-28.el7
May 10 07:39:05 Updated: glibc-common.x86_64 2.17-222.el7
May 10 07:39:05 Updated: nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 3.34.0-2.el7
May 10 07:39:06 Updated: glibc.x86_64 2.17-222.el7
May 10 07:39:06 Updated: bash.x86_64 4.2.46-30.el7
May 10 07:39:06 Updated: nspr.x86_64 4.17.0-1.el7
May 10 07:39:06 Updated: nss-util.x86_64 3.34.0-2.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: libsepol.x86_64 2.5-8.1.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: libselinux.x86_64 2.5-12.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: libcom_err.x86_64 1.42.9-11.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: audit-libs.x86_64 2.8.1-3.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: info.x86_64 5.1-5.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: libdb.x86_64 5.3.21-24.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: libuuid.x86_64 2.23.2-52.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0.170-4.el7
May 10 07:39:07 Updated: libstdc++.x86_64 4.8.5-28.el7
May 10 07:39:08 Updated: cpio.x86_64 2.11-27.el7
May 10 07:39:08 Updated: libattr.x86_64 2.4.46-13.el7
May 10 07:39:08 Updated: libacl.x86_64 2.2.51-14.el7
May 10 07:39:08 Updated: libsemanage.x86_64 2.5-11.el7
May 10 07:39:08 Updated: e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 1.42.9-11.el7
May 10 07:39:08 Updated: nss-softokn.x86_64 3.34.0-2.el7
May 10 07:39:09 Updated: ca-certificates.noarch 2017.2.20-71.el7
May 10 07:39:10 Updated: coreutils.x86_64 8.22-21.el7
May 10 07:39:10 Updated: openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
May 10 07:39:11 Updated: krb5-libs.x86_64 1.15.1-18.el7
May 10 07:39:11 Updated: libpwquality.x86_64 1.2.3-5.el7
May 10 07:39:12 Updated: pam.x86_64 1.1.8-22.el7
May 10 07:39:12 Updated: libblkid.x86_64 2.23.2-52.el7
May 10 07:39:12 Updated: centos-release.x86_64 7-5.1804.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:12 Updated: libmount.x86_64 2.23.2-52.el7
May 10 07:39:13 Updated: glib2.x86_64 2.54.2-2.el7
May 10 07:39:13 Updated: shared-mime-info.x86_64 1.8-4.el7
May 10 07:39:13 Updated: cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64 2.1.26-23.el7
May 10 07:39:16 Updated: python-libs.x86_64 2.7.5-68.el7
May 10 07:39:16 Updated: python.x86_64 2.7.5-68.el7
May 10 07:39:16 Updated: net-snmp-libs.x86_64 1:5.7.2-32.el7
May 10 07:39:16 Updated: gzip.x86_64 1.5-10.el7
May 10 07:39:17 Updated: setup.noarch 2.8.71-9.el7
May 10 07:39:17 Updated: filesystem.x86_64 3.2-25.el7
May 10 07:39:19 Updated: binutils.x86_64 2.27-27.base.el7
May 10 07:39:19 Updated: iptables.x86_64 1.4.21-24.el7
May 10 07:39:19 Updated: iproute.x86_64 4.11.0-14.el7
May 10 07:39:20 Updated: ethtool.x86_64 2:4.8-7.el7
May 10 07:39:20 Updated: libpcap.x86_64 14:1.5.3-11.el7
May 10 07:39:20 Updated: pciutils-libs.x86_64 3.5.1-3.el7
May 10 07:39:20 Installed: lz4.x86_64 1.7.5-2.el7
May 10 07:39:20 Updated: perl-IO-Socket-IP.noarch 0.21-5.el7
May 10 07:39:20 Updated: bind-license.noarch 32:9.9.4-61.el7
May 10 07:39:21 Updated: bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7
May 10 07:39:21 Updated: bind-libs-lite.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7
May 10 07:39:22 Updated: nmap-ncat.x86_64 2:6.40-13.el7
May 10 07:39:23 Updated: cpp.x86_64 4.8.5-28.el7
May 10 07:39:23 Updated: libselinux-python.x86_64 2.5-12.el7
May 10 07:39:23 Updated: python-slip.noarch 0.4.0-4.el7
May 10 07:39:23 Updated: python-slip-dbus.noarch 0.4.0-4.el7
May 10 07:39:24 Updated: python-firewall.noarch 0.4.4.4-14.el7
May 10 07:39:24 Updated: python-perf.x86_64 3.10.0-862.el7
May 10 07:39:24 Updated: libkadm5.x86_64 1.15.1-18.el7
May 10 07:39:24 Updated: openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
May 10 07:39:33 Updated: linux-firmware.noarch 20180220-62.git6d51311.el7
May 10 07:39:34 Updated: nss.x86_64 3.34.0-4.el7
May 10 07:39:34 Updated: nss-sysinit.x86_64 3.34.0-4.el7
May 10 07:39:34 Updated: nss-tools.x86_64 3.34.0-4.el7
May 10 07:39:34 Updated: logrotate.x86_64 3.8.6-15.el7
May 10 07:39:34 Installed: perl-Mozilla-CA.noarch 20130114-5.el7
May 10 07:39:34 Updated: tar.x86_64 2:1.26-34.el7
May 10 07:39:35 Updated: acl.x86_64 2.2.51-14.el7
May 10 07:39:35 Updated: vim-minimal.x86_64 2:7.4.160-4.el7
May 10 07:39:35 Updated: device-mapper-persistent-data.x86_64 0.7.3-3.el7
May 10 07:39:35 Updated: mozjs17.x86_64 17.0.0-20.el7
May 10 07:39:36 Updated: libstdc++-devel.x86_64 4.8.5-28.el7
May 10 07:39:36 Updated: libdb-utils.x86_64 5.3.21-24.el7
May 10 07:39:36 Updated: libcurl.x86_64 7.29.0-46.el7
May 10 07:39:36 Updated: curl.x86_64 7.29.0-46.el7
May 10 07:39:36 Updated: rpm-libs.x86_64 4.11.3-32.el7
May 10 07:39:37 Updated: rpm.x86_64 4.11.3-32.el7
May 10 07:39:37 Updated: openldap.x86_64 2.4.44-13.el7
May 10 07:39:37 Updated: libuser.x86_64 0.60-9.el7
May 10 07:39:37 Updated: rpm-build-libs.x86_64 4.11.3-32.el7
May 10 07:39:37 Updated: rpm-python.x86_64 4.11.3-32.el7
May 10 07:39:37 Updated: yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch 1.1.31-45.el7
May 10 07:39:38 Updated: yum.noarch 3.4.3-158.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:38 Updated: net-snmp-agent-libs.x86_64 1:5.7.2-32.el7
May 10 07:39:38 Updated: libgomp.x86_64 4.8.5-28.el7
May 10 07:39:39 Updated: libss.x86_64 1.42.9-11.el7
May 10 07:39:39 Updated: libcom_err-devel.x86_64 1.42.9-11.el7
May 10 07:39:39 Updated: libselinux-utils.x86_64 2.5-12.el7
May 10 07:39:39 Updated: libsepol-devel.x86_64 2.5-8.1.el7
May 10 07:39:39 Updated: libselinux-devel.x86_64 2.5-12.el7
May 10 07:39:40 Updated: krb5-devel.x86_64 1.15.1-18.el7
May 10 07:39:40 Updated: libteam.x86_64 1.27-4.el7
May 10 07:39:41 Updated: kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 3.10.0-862.el7
May 10 07:39:41 Updated: numactl-libs.x86_64 2.0.9-7.el7
May 10 07:39:41 Updated: kmod-libs.x86_64 20-21.el7
May 10 07:39:41 Updated: procps-ng.x86_64 3.3.10-17.el7
May 10 07:39:41 Updated: kpartx.x86_64 0.4.9-119.el7
May 10 07:39:41 Updated: device-mapper.x86_64 7:1.02.146-4.el7
May 10 07:39:42 Updated: util-linux.x86_64 2.23.2-52.el7
May 10 07:39:43 Updated: device-mapper-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.146-4.el7
May 10 07:39:43 Updated: cryptsetup-libs.x86_64 1.7.4-4.el7
May 10 07:39:44 Updated: dracut.x86_64 033-535.el7
May 10 07:39:44 Updated: kmod.x86_64 20-21.el7
May 10 07:39:44 Updated: elfutils-libs.x86_64 0.170-4.el7
May 10 07:39:44 Updated: systemd-libs.x86_64 219-57.el7
May 10 07:39:45 Updated: dbus-libs.x86_64 1:1.10.24-7.el7
May 10 07:39:48 Updated: systemd.x86_64 219-57.el7
May 10 07:39:49 Updated: dbus.x86_64 1:1.10.24-7.el7
May 10 07:39:49 Updated: elfutils-default-yama-scope.noarch 0.170-4.el7
May 10 07:39:50 Updated: initscripts.x86_64 9.49.41-1.el7
May 10 07:39:50 Updated: systemd-sysv.x86_64 219-57.el7
May 10 07:39:50 Updated: device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.146-4.el7
May 10 07:39:50 Updated: wpa_supplicant.x86_64 1:2.6-9.el7
May 10 07:39:51 Updated: polkit.x86_64 0.112-14.el7
May 10 07:39:51 Updated: cronie-anacron.x86_64 1.4.11-19.el7
May 10 07:39:51 Updated: cronie.x86_64 1.4.11-19.el7
May 10 07:39:52 Updated: NetworkManager-libnm.x86_64 1:1.10.2-13.el7
May 10 07:39:53 Updated: NetworkManager.x86_64 1:1.10.2-13.el7
May 10 07:39:53 Updated: dhcp-libs.x86_64 12:4.2.5-68.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:53 Updated: openssh.x86_64 7.4p1-16.el7
May 10 07:39:54 Updated: policycoreutils.x86_64 2.5-22.el7
May 10 07:39:54 Updated: selinux-policy.noarch 3.13.1-192.el7
May 10 07:39:54 Updated: dhcp-common.x86_64 12:4.2.5-68.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:55 Updated: dhclient.x86_64 12:4.2.5-68.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:55 Updated: dracut-network.x86_64 033-535.el7
May 10 07:39:55 Updated: device-mapper-event.x86_64 7:1.02.146-4.el7
May 10 07:39:56 Updated: lvm2-libs.x86_64 7:2.02.177-4.el7
May 10 07:39:56 Updated: rpcbind.x86_64 0.2.0-44.el7
May 10 07:39:56 Updated: cyrus-sasl.x86_64 2.1.26-23.el7
May 10 07:39:57 Updated: ebtables.x86_64 2.0.10-16.el7
May 10 07:39:57 Updated: ntpdate.x86_64 4.2.6p5-28.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:58 Updated: hwdata.x86_64 0.252-8.8.el7
May 10 07:39:58 Updated: libpciaccess.x86_64 0.14-1.el7
May 10 07:39:58 Updated: libdrm.x86_64 2.4.83-2.el7
May 10 07:39:59 Updated: teamd.x86_64 1.27-4.el7
May 10 07:39:59 Updated: plymouth-core-libs.x86_64 0.8.9-0.31.20140113.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:59 Updated: plymouth-scripts.x86_64 0.8.9-0.31.20140113.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:59 Updated: plymouth.x86_64 0.8.9-0.31.20140113.el7.centos
May 10 07:39:59 Updated: virt-what.x86_64 1.18-4.el7
May 10 07:39:59 Updated: firewalld-filesystem.noarch 0.4.4.4-14.el7
May 10 07:39:59 Updated: quota-nls.noarch 1:4.01-17.el7
May 10 07:40:00 Updated: kernel-headers.x86_64 3.10.0-862.el7
May 10 07:40:01 Updated: glibc-headers.x86_64 2.17-222.el7
May 10 07:40:01 Updated: glibc-devel.x86_64 2.17-222.el7
May 10 07:40:03 Updated: gcc.x86_64 4.8.5-28.el7
May 10 07:40:04 Updated: gcc-c++.x86_64 4.8.5-28.el7
May 10 07:40:04 Updated: quota.x86_64 1:4.01-17.el7
May 10 07:40:05 Updated: firewalld.noarch 0.4.4.4-14.el7
May 10 07:40:05 Updated: tuned.noarch 2.9.0-1.el7
May 10 07:40:05 Updated: NetworkManager-team.x86_64 1:1.10.2-13.el7
May 10 07:40:05 Updated: ntp.x86_64 4.2.6p5-28.el7.centos
May 10 07:40:05 Updated: cyrus-sasl-devel.x86_64 2.1.26-23.el7
May 10 07:40:06 Updated: lvm2.x86_64 7:2.02.177-4.el7
May 10 07:40:06 Updated: kexec-tools.x86_64 2.0.15-13.el7
May 10 07:40:20 Updated: selinux-policy-targeted.noarch 3.13.1-192.el7
May 10 07:40:20 Updated: openssh-clients.x86_64 7.4p1-16.el7
May 10 07:40:21 Updated: openssh-server.x86_64 7.4p1-16.el7
May 10 07:40:21 Updated: NetworkManager-wifi.x86_64 1:1.10.2-13.el7
May 10 07:40:21 Updated: NetworkManager-tui.x86_64 1:1.10.2-13.el7
May 10 07:40:21 Updated: yum-cron.noarch 3.4.3-158.el7.centos
May 10 07:40:22 Updated: audit.x86_64 2.8.1-3.el7
May 10 07:40:22 Updated: net-snmp.x86_64 1:5.7.2-32.el7
May 10 07:40:28 Installed: kernel.x86_64 3.10.0-862.el7
May 10 07:40:28 Updated: rsync.x86_64 3.1.2-4.el7
May 10 07:40:29 Updated: bind.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7
May 10 07:40:29 Updated: biosdevname.x86_64 0.7.3-1.el7
May 10 07:40:29 Updated: rsyslog.x86_64 8.24.0-16.el7
May 10 07:40:29 Updated: systemd-devel.x86_64 219-57.el7
May 10 07:40:29 Updated: irqbalance.x86_64 3:1.0.7-11.el7
May 10 07:40:30 Updated: microcode_ctl.x86_64 2:2.1-29.el7
May 10 07:40:30 Updated: dracut-config-rescue.x86_64 033-535.el7
May 10 07:40:30 Updated: parted.x86_64 3.1-29.el7
May 10 07:40:31 Updated: kernel-tools.x86_64 3.10.0-862.el7
May 10 07:40:34 Updated: openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
May 10 07:40:34 Updated: e2fsprogs.x86_64 1.42.9-11.el7
May 10 07:40:34 Updated: yum-utils.noarch 1.1.31-45.el7
May 10 07:40:35 Updated: sudo.x86_64 1.8.19p2-13.el7
May 10 07:40:36 Updated: libcurl-devel.x86_64 7.29.0-46.el7
May 10 07:40:36 Updated: perl-IO-Socket-SSL.noarch 1.94-7.el7
May 10 07:40:37 Updated: mailx.x86_64 12.5-19.el7
May 10 07:40:38 Updated: nmap.x86_64 2:6.40-13.el7
May 10 07:40:39 Updated: bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7
May 10 07:40:39 Updated: perl-HTTP-Daemon.noarch 6.01-7.el7
May 10 07:40:40 Updated: net-snmp-utils.x86_64 1:5.7.2-32.el7
May 10 07:40:40 Updated: systemtap-sdt-devel.x86_64 3.2-4.el7
May 10 07:40:41 Updated: xfsprogs.x86_64 4.5.0-15.el7
May 10 07:40:44 Updated: screen.x86_64 4.1.0-0.25.20120314git3c2946.el7
May 10 07:40:44 Updated: alsa-lib.x86_64 1.1.4.1-2.el7
May 10 07:40:44 Updated: gperftools-libs.x86_64 2.6.1-1.el7
May 10 07:40:45 Updated: libdb-devel.x86_64 5.3.21-24.el7
May 10 07:40:45 Updated: lsof.x86_64 4.87-5.el7
May 10 07:41:06 Installed: kernel-devel.x86_64 3.10.0-862.el7
May 10 07:41:06 Updated: unzip.x86_64 6.0-19.el7
May 10 07:41:06 Updated: iprutils.x86_64 2.4.15.1-1.el7
May 10 07:41:06 Updated: perl-version.x86_64 3:0.99.07-3.el7
May 10 07:41:07 Updated: iwl135-firmware.noarch 18.168.6.1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:07 Updated: iwl2030-firmware.noarch 18.168.6.1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:08 Updated: iwl7260-firmware.noarch 22.0.7.0-62.el7
May 10 07:41:08 Updated: iwl6050-firmware.noarch 41.28.5.1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:08 Updated: iwl4965-firmware.noarch 228.61.2.24-62.el7
May 10 07:41:09 Updated: iwl3160-firmware.noarch 22.0.7.0-62.el7
May 10 07:41:09 Updated: iwl6000-firmware.noarch 9.221.4.1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:09 Updated: iwl5000-firmware.noarch 8.83.5.1_1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:09 Updated: perl-Getopt-Long.noarch 2.40-3.el7
May 10 07:41:09 Updated: iwl3945-firmware.noarch 15.32.2.9-62.el7
May 10 07:41:09 Updated: iwl100-firmware.noarch 39.31.5.1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:10 Updated: iwl6000g2b-firmware.noarch 17.168.5.2-62.el7
May 10 07:41:10 Updated: iwl105-firmware.noarch 18.168.6.1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:10 Updated: iwl6000g2a-firmware.noarch 17.168.5.3-62.el7
May 10 07:41:10 Updated: iwl2000-firmware.noarch 18.168.6.1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:12 Updated: iwl7265-firmware.noarch 22.0.7.0-62.el7
May 10 07:41:12 Updated: iwl1000-firmware.noarch 1:39.31.5.1-62.el7
May 10 07:41:12 Updated: iwl5150-firmware.noarch 8.24.2.2-62.el7
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution seems to be restarting Apache.

(I haven't had coffee today yet.)